# Scala: pattern matching on a path-dependent type

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, path-dependent-type

Can't figure out why Scala 2.13 is unhappy about pattern matching here

```scala
  trait A {
    sealed trait T
    case class TImpl() extends T
  }

  trait Fail[B <: A] {
    val a: B // no error if `a: A`
    def foo(t : a.T): Unit = t match {
      case _: a.TImpl => // "match may not be exhaustive. It would fail on the following input: TImpl()"
    }
  }
```

Any reasonable workaround?
Seems to be fine with Dotty

Comment: Do you need a workaround for what? Do you want to swiich the warning off?

Comment: A workaround would be useful. An explanation too, if possible. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see why in principle the pattern  matching can be not exhaustive, for instance see the following example

```
trait A {
  sealed trait T
  case class TImpl() extends T
}

trait Fail[B <: A] {
  val a: B
  def foo(t : a.T): Unit = t match {
    case _: a.TImpl => 
  }
}

class B extends A
val b = new B
class FailImpl extends Fail[b.type] {
  override val a: b.type = b
}
val fail: Fail[b.type] = new FailImpl

class C
case class CImpl() extends C with b.T
val x = CImpl()
fail.foo(x) // MatchError
```

You could say that actually we didn't have `C`. Well, compiler should be smart enough to figure out that.

If you want to switch the warning off you can write `@unchecked`

```
def foo(t : a.T): Unit = (t: @unchecked) match {
  case _: a.TImpl => 
}
```

According to specification,

> If the selector of a pattern match is an instance of a sealed class, the compilation of pattern matching can emit warnings which diagnose that a given set of patterns is not exhaustive, i.e. that there is a possibility of a `MatchError` being raised at run-time.

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-expressions

Compiler **can** emit a warning but not **must**. So absence of warning doesn't guarantee that a pattern matching is exhaustive.

Comment: OK, my confusion was based on the wrong assumption that `sealed` class can only be extended in the same compilation unit, i.e. `A` in this case. Your example shows to exploit the fact that it is not true.

Do you know how Dotty manages to do a better job here? There's no warning in my example, but it does warn if I add another case class without corresponding matching branch.

Comment: @eprst The compilation unit is the entire file, not `A`.

Comment: Fair enough. And to answer my question above, it's the same in Dotty. There's no warning, but `MatchError` still happens. I'd limit `sealed` to the tighter scope.